# how to replace dropdown menu with swagger UI plugin?

Tags: reactjs, plugins, swagger-ui

I'm working in a springboot project with swagger UI(openAPI 3.0). My task is to replace the swagger UI [dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8RS.png) with other html elements(ul, li) to make it more friendly for styling.

I know the dropdown menu is defined in topbar.jsx and exposed as a ReactComponent, so my thought is to write a swagger UI wrapComponents plugin to override the "render()" method defined in topbar.jsx.

here is the [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45eh7.png) of swagger UI

here is the [swagger UI config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grOOz.png) (defined in a JS file)

here is the [plugin definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brKHX.png), also defined in the same JS file; for test purpose, I just want to display 'hello world' on the topbar after applying this plugin.

unfortunately, the above configs doesn't work(the 'hello world' doesn't appear in browser and I didn't see any error), so my question is:

1. Did I miss anything with this swagger UI plugin approach?
2. Is there another way to fulfill my task(replace dropdown menu in topbar with other html element - ul, li, div) without using swagger UI plugin?

thanks for help!

Comment: You might get better answers if you ask this in the Swagger UI repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: The entire point of stack overflow is for developers to ask each other questions @Helen